# How to add dependency on library that is published locally for Play Project?

Tags: scala, build, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have a Play project that is intended to be a library that I would like to publish locally during development phase.

I can achieve this by running `publish-local`

My question is how to add dependency in the main project so that in the main project we could access the utilities defined in the local library?

It seems I need to add the dependency in Build.scala.
Here's what I would do for external libray:
`"com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0"`

What would I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a `Resolver` precising your local ivy repository:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("Local repo", file("/home/USER/.ivy2/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

You may want to manage resolvers ordering/priorities (meaning, start searching from local repo, then if not found, try external repositories). In this case, you must deal with [Proxy Repositories](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html).